# When initializing a backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

How do I make it so that a function runs every time a backbone.js view is initialized?

I'm looking for something that I can put on outside of my normal view code, as an extension to backbone.js.

The idea is to reduce the amount of boilerplate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Javascript is not a true object oriented programing language, you can't use inheritance to solve your problem as you could if it was java or c#.

One possible solution is to use the factory design pattern.

Instead of instantiating your view directly, you can call a factory method that will instantiate your view.

```
var viewFactory = function(view, viewOptions) {
  //perform your boilerplate code
  return new view(viewOptions);
}

AView = Backbone.View.extend({});

var person = new Backbone.Model({name: 'Paul'});
var view = viewFactory(AView, { model: person });
```

Here's a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/paulyoder/6eyyc/1/)

It's not as an elegant solution that is possible with other languages, but it does the job.

Comment: Yep, this is what I'm doing for now. It's an acceptable / good solution.

Answer (score 3):

use the builtin backbone.js initialize function:

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-constructor

```
var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    alert('View Initialized');
  }
});
```

EDIT: I should be more clear.

In the words of Patrick Ewing found here http://podcast.rubyonrails.org/programs/1/episodes/railsconf-2007:

`"if it walks like a duck and talks like a duck, it’s a duck, right? So if this duck is not giving you the noise that you want, you’ve got to just punch that duck until it returns what you expect"`

Duck Punch (or Monkey Patch if you prefer) the Backbone object.

```
Backbone.View.prototype.initialize = function(){
  alert('I overrode the default initialize function!');
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you're going to overwrite your overwrite when you make your new views

Comment: Only if you define an initialize function in the view.

Comment: You can just call your super method in the override. ClassYouExtend.prototype.initialize.call(this); and your parents initilize will be called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Backbone.Events.

On the top level of your app or on the global object:

```
app.eventManager = {};
_.extend(app.eventManager, Backbone.Events);
app.eventManager.bind("newView", app.yourfunction(view));
```

And in the initialize method of any view you want to trigger your function:

```
app.eventManager.trigger("newView", this);
```

where "this" is the view instance passed as the "view" parameter to your function.

Comment: there's no built in event, so that means triggering manually, that's not ideal.

Comment: Why exactly  isn't it ideal to trigger custom events?